# I'm trying to run the following python code and it states no module named get_config

Tags: python

I've tried installing the get_config package however the following error message appears:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement get_config
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for get_config

Here is the Python file I'm running:

```
import time
import tweepy
import operator
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from get_config import get_config

env = get_config()

consumer_key = env.get('CONSUMER_KEY')
consumer_secret = env.get('CONSUMER_SECRET')
access_token = env.get('ACCESS_TOKEN')
access_secret = env.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')
```

Comment: How did you even manage to get this much indentation!?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Is the `get_config` method from a package, and is that package installed?

Comment: I'm using python 3.5.2 and using jupyter as GUI. I am calling a get_config file and I receive the following error in jupyter:

Comment: ImportError                               
---> 10 from get_config import get_config
      3 import functools
      4 import json
----> 5 from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
      6 from StringIO import StringIO
      7 

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'